# A question about Green's function in two-dimension system

Tags: calculus

In Arfken and Weber's Mathematical methods for physicists, 6th edition p597, it is said

> Consider $$ \nabla_1^2 G(\mathbf{r_1},\mathbf{r_2}) = -\delta(\mathbf{r_1}- \mathbf{r_2})  \tag{9.171} $$

After integrating over $d\tau_1$ at the right-hand-side of Eq. (9.173) and apply the Gauss' theorem on the left-hand-side, we find

> $$ \int \nabla_1 G(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2) \cdot d \sigma_1 =-1 \tag{9.173} $$
>
> If we are in two-dimensional space, Eq. (9.173) is satisfied by taking
> $$ \frac{ \partial}{ \partial \rho_{12} } G(\mathrm{\rho}_1, \mathrm{\rho}_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{|\rho_1 - \rho_2| }  \tag{9.176} $$

where $\rho=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}, \rho_{12}=|\rho_1 - \rho_2| $. Interating Eq. (9.176) we obtain

> $$G(\rho_1,\rho_2) = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln | \rho_1 - \rho_2| \tag{9.177} $$

I have two questions about Eqs. (9.176) and (9.177).

(i) If I integrate (9.176), why I miss a minus sign?
$$ \oint \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{| \rho_1 - \rho_2 | } dl= 1 $$

(ii) If I differentiate (9.177) in order to get (9.176), I also miss a minus sign. Where are  the problems?
$$ \frac{ \partial}{ \partial \rho_{12} }  \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{|\rho_1 - \rho_2| }= - \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{| \rho_1 - \rho_2|}  $$?